# docker puppeteer MathJax Chinese character wrong letter spacing

Tags: docker, puppeteer, mathjax

I'm trying to render latex formula string in puppeteer, the problem is, when running inside docker, the Chinese characters don't render well, getting too little letter spacing

[image]

the correct result should be (which I get in my local development env, without docker)

[image]

my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && apk add --no-cache chromium \
  nss \
  freetype \
  harfbuzz \
  ca-certificates \
  ttf-freefont

ENV CHROME_BIN="/usr/bin/chromium-browser"\
  PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD="true" \
  UPLOAD_ENV="test"

WORKDIR /app

COPY  package.json .
COPY  .npmrc .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 9999

CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

my puppeteer launch code:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: true,
      executablePath: process.env.CHROME_BIN || undefined,
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox',
        '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
        '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
        '--no-first-run',
        '--no-zygote',
        '--single-process',
        '--disable-gpu',
        '--font-render-hinting=none'
      ]
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

after installing some extra fonts, the problem is solved.

update Dockerfile with code below

```
RUN echo @edge http://nl.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing >> /etc/apk/repositories
RUN apk --no-cache upgrade && apk add --no-cache \
  chromium \
  nss \
  freetype \
  harfbuzz \
  ca-certificates \
  ttf-freefont \
  wqy-zenhei@edge
```